# I have to change GridView Data on Dropdown Selected Index Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to change Gridview detail on DropDown Selected Value Change. This is My code but it is not working. It is not showing data in GridView. GridView is empty when I change index of DropDownList.

index.aspx.cs Code:

```
    protected void DropDownListDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Doctor WHERE Doc_Id=" + DropDownListDoctor.SelectedValue + "";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridViewDoctorDetail.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

index.aspx Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<label>Select Doctor Name</label>
<br />
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListDoctor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="Doctor_DataSource" DataTextField="DocName" 
        DataValueField="Doc_Id" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Doctor_DataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=IM-82B70624D72D;Initial Catalog=AppointmentScheduler;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=za3452432760za" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Doc_Id], [DocName] FROM [Doctor]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <label>Doctor Detail</label>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewDoctorDetail" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="339px" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DoctorDetail_SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=IM-82B70624D72D;Initial Catalog=AppointmentScheduler;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=za3452432760za" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Doctor] WHERE ([Doc_Id] = @Doc_Id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListDoctor" DefaultValue="1" 
                Name="Doc_Id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
GridViewDoctorDetail.DataBind();
```

to your behind code. When the postback occurs the gridview loses its previous content and without that it doesn't have any data binded to it.

```
protected void DropDownListDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Doctor WHERE Doc_Id=" + DropDownListDoctor.SelectedValue + "";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridViewDoctorDetail.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewDoctorDetail.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that data is coming back from the SQL query?

Comment: Also, you have AutoGenerateColumns="False". You need to add the columns for anything to show up as well.

Comment: Yes. AutoGeneratedColumn is false.

Comment: Showing this error when I change DropDownIndex:- {Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridViewDoctorDetail'.  Remove one definition}

Comment: Are you adding columns manually and just didn't post the code?

Comment: Yes I was adding Column manually thats why it is showing this error.

Comment: Are you setting the DataSourceID for your gridview somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I was setting on design hand.

Comment: You need to remove that and use your page_load or other function to populate the gridview initially

Comment: Dear friend, how can I setting up on page_load? I am not getting. Can you explain?

Comment: If you are binding the gridview when the page is loaded you need to call your sql statement and set the gridview to bind that as the datasource. If you aren't loading information into the gridview when the page is loaded, then you don't need to do anything other that get rid of the datasourceid element

Comment: Yes, I don't want to load any data on page load, but I have to load data on DropDownSelected Index change but that is not working. You said to me that put databind, I have done that but still not showing data in Gridview.

Comment: Set AutoGeneratedColumn="true" and see if you get results.

Comment: Thanks My friend, When I Set AutoGeneratedColumn="true", It start working.

Comment: Now that you know it works, you can further control which columns show by manually defining them and setting AutoGeneratedColumn="false".

Comment: Error {A field or property with the name 'Click on Checkbox' was not found on the selected data source.}

Comment: I have to add a Column manually but when I add and run that is show above error.

Comment: You'll need to post your updated code.  You should start a new topic to figure this question out.